# What unit does getBoundingClientRect return in?

Tags: units-of-measurement, getboundingclientrect

I know that `getBoundingClientRect()` returns an object of type `ClientRect` or `DOMRect`, and each usually has properties like `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`, and more.  And if you `typeof` those properties, you get `Number`.

So my question is, that `Number` is an amount of what?  Pixels `px`, points `pt`, percentage `%`, and things like that are possible answers.  I think it is pixels, but I am not completely sure about that.  Could anyone confirm this?

Comment: Confirmed. It's pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to [@Ken White](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65223560/what-unit-does-getboundingclientrect-return-in?noredirect=1#comment115308671_65223560) for confirming the answer:

`getBoundingClientRect()` returns an array of `Number`s that specify an amount of **pixels (px)**.

Comment: So why is the returned number a floating point..?

Comment: @Redu: The width of your element (in pixels) could be a floating point number. This is because although a 5px wide element wouldn't look any different from a 5.2px wide element, when you zoom in to 500%, you can see that one of them is 25px (on the screen) and the other is 26px. This is why it makes sense that numbers returned from `getBoundingClientRect()` are floating point numbers. The fraction of a pixel counts.